# How to access the popup DOM from the parent window after the popup refreshes itself?

Tags: javascript

I have a parent page which opens a popup.

I can access the DOM of the popup from the parent but after the popup refresh itself, I can't access it anymore (the click event on the button is not received).

Sample of my code:

```
var popup = window.open('http://d.com/popup.html', 'my_popup', 'width=1200px, height=800px');
popup.window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var myButton = popup.window.document.getElementById('myButton');
    myButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
      console.log("click");
    })
});
```

Everything works perfectly until the popup has to refresh itself :/

Any idea?

Comment: if you are willing to use jQuery, then the `on()` function would help you: the problem you are facing (if i understand correctly) is that you are accessing an object that did not exist before (since it was only created after the reload). I cannot help you with play JS at the moment, though.

Comment: How does the popup refresh itself? Is it from the popup directly or the parent window?

Comment: The popup refresh by itself (and unfortunately, it's a legacy code which would be complicated to change)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're experiencing is that, as Burki stated before on comments, when your popup reloads, the myButton object is recreated and the eventListener you added before is no longer wirred to him.

Probably your best option is to move (if it's possible) the eventListener code to the popup.html page, as it will execute each time the popup is reloaded.

Maybe using jQuery's .on() method to bind both your eventListeners would also help, although I'm not 100% sure of that on this scenario.

Check if the load event code in the page is firing when the popup reloads

Comment: I don't think the load is firing either because then it would just find the new button and attach the event again.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace, you're right, the load event is not fired a second time in the parent page. For the moment I've moved my code in the popup, as suggested by Bardo, but I don't like this solution because the popup is used somewhere else.